# Appending html as variable doesnt interpret tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable which contains text and a tag. When appending variable to the element the tag isnt interpreted as a tag. Instead its interpreted as text.

Take this example:

```
var translationWrapper = $("<div class='list-label'></div>");
translationWrapper.html('<span> test </span>');
var translationContent = "";
translationContent += 'Testtext <em> test </em>';
translationWrapper.append(translationContent);
```

If I do this. The em tag isn't interpreted as a tag. Instead its interpreted as text. How can I let it interpret the tag ?

Comment: jQuery [`append(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) takes a String, the documentations gives an example `$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );`. I ran your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90k92a02/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks. It showed me that this doesn't cause the problem. So the problem seems to be in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Before append you need to convert it to jQuery object

```
translationContent += 'Testtext <em> test </em>';
translationWrapper.append($(translationContent));
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what I missed.

Comment: @Kbi - If this is your solution, then please accept it.

Comment: I cannot accept it until 12 minutes pass. I found one more thing: If i create the variable with translationContent = ""; it does not work. Do I have to generate it as a jQuery object ?

Comment: Please repeat question or provide jsfiddle with code

Answer (score 0):

The comment from George Lee "solved" my issue. The problem is not in the provided code. It seems to be in my data.

using

```
jQuery(translationWrapper).append(translationContent);
```

works fine